# selenium-webdriver issues triggering hover via move_to_element on ie10

Tags: selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-10, remotewebdriver

I'm using remote webdriver to test different configurations on SauceLabs.  One of my pages has an ajax function that loads an extended form section.  The load is triggered by either the blur of a particular form element, or if someone hovers over the .form-actions div.  I'm trying to re-create this behaviour through webdriver.

The following behaves as expected on ie9 and chrome (the second part of the form loads), but stops working on ie10:

```
    nxt_btn = self.sel.find_element_by_css_selector(
        NEXT_BTN_SELECTOR)
    ActionChains(self.sel).move_to_element(nxt_btn).perform()
    self.wait_until_visible('input[name="next_to_load"]')
```

The form expands correctly if I bring up the ie10 browser and move the mouse in manual testing, so it seems that it's the remove webdriver that isn't triggering either the 'blur' of the input or the 'hover' over the form-actions div.

Is there a way I can change either my webdriver test code or my site to make this work with ie10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I ran tests on IE (IE11, in my case), hovering worked fine (locally) with this code

```
hover = ActionChains(self.browser).move_to_element(elem)                   
hover.perform()
```

When I ran this on Saucelabs, no luck. I finally implemented in javascript (using code I found [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2067#c57)). I ended up doing this

```python
def hover_over(self, params):                                                
    if self.driver.desired_capabilities['browserName'] in ['safari', 'internet explorer']:
        print "Javascript Hovering over = " + params['menu']                
        self.js_hover_over(params )                                        
    else:                                                                   
        print "Std Hovering over = " + params['menu']                       
        self.std_hover_over(params)                                       


def js_hover_over(self, params):                                          
    js_script = ''.join(["var elem = document.getElementById('",            
        params['menu'],                                                        
        "');",                                                              
        "if (document.createEvent) {",                                      
        "var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');",                    
        "evObj.initEvent('mouseover', true, false);",                        
        "elem.dispatchEvent(evObj);",                                          
        "} else if (document.createEventObject) {",                        
        "elem.fireEvent('onmouseover');",                                      
        "}"])                                                               
    self.driver.execute_script(js_script)                                   

def std_hover_over(self, params):                                            
    elem =self.driver.find_element_by_id(params['menu'])                       
    hover = ActionChains(self.browser).move_to_element(elem)                   
    hover.perform()
```